# Rpart using Caret changes names of Factors

Tags: r, caret, rpart

If I have a factor e.g. sexe with two levels MALE and FEMELLE let's say, using rpart alone I get splits that say for example Sexe = Male and then a yes no split. However using rpart with caret I get a weird renaming of variables:

[image]

this also causes a problem with the predict function as now my variable isn't called sexe anymore but sexeMALE. Is there a way around this? Also it's a factor variable what does >=.5 mean in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Male is probably internally represented as 1 and non-male is 0 so it's just  splitting in the middle of its domain value. Hard to say what's going on with age since you haven't described the data. Adding the level to the factor name is standard R parlance. You would only supply list(sexe="MALE") to `predict`. Voting to close for lack of data or code, but more importantly because you are just asking for model interpretation.

Comment: Actually everything is a factor variable. Age actually has 3 levels. AGEE is one of the levels, other levels are ADO and ADULTE. So it's doing the same thing to my 3 level factor. I just find it odd because rpart alone does not cause this issue. I'm wondering if its a problem with my data frame. But I've checked and everything is defined as a factor.

Comment: Still lacking code and data, but I suspect that the plot function is being dispatched to a different function than `plot.rpart`. You should look at the class attribute of your object and then .... look at the documentation ... because we cannot see any details on your dataframe. (I doubt the problem is in your data. More likely in the parameters of the `train` and `plot` calls.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably used the formula method with `train` which converts the factors to dummy variables. Most functions in R that use the formula method do the same. `rpart`, `randomForest`, `naiveBayes` and a few others do not since they are able to model the categories without needing numeric encodings of that data.

The naming that you see is what is generated by `model.matrix`.

If you want to keep the factors as factors, use the non-formula method, e.g.

```
train(x, y)
```

Max

Comment: Which other caret methods are able to model the categories without needing numeric encodings?

Comment: Assuming the OP does want to use the formula interface (regardless of why), how should OP prepare a data.frame that includes factor variables prior to training? e.g., `newsourcedata = data.frame(model.matrix(object=modelformula, data = mysourcedataframe), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`?